# React MUI Select Object not showing selected value

Tags: reactjs, object, material-ui

Hey I am stuck with a problem, I using MUI select function for me to select a country.  not sure why when I selected the country it change its value but when inside the select box it does not show anything.

```
const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState({});
 const handleChangeCountry = (event) => {
    setCountryValue(event.target.value);
  };
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 400 }}>
                <InputLabel id="country-label">Country</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="country-label"
                  id="country"
                  value={selectedCountry}
                  onChange={handleChangeCountry}
                  MenuProps={MenuProps}
                >
                  {countryList.map((data,index) => (
                    <MenuItem
                      key={data.name}
                      value={data}
                    >
                      {data.name}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
<p className="text-black">{selectedCountry.name}</p>
<p className="text-black">{JSON.stringify(selectedCountry, null, 2)}</p>
```

[image]

As you can see, below the blue background color text show the country that I selected, but in the select box is not showing. Not sure where I am doing wrong.
Thanks for helping advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useState` hook has the set function called `setSelectedCountry` but on `handleChangeCountry` you try to use `setCountryValue` which does not update `selectedCountry` based on your provided code, please change it like this:

```
 const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState({});
 const handleChangeCountry = (event) => {
    setSelectedCountry(event.target.value);
  };
```

Also, it seems that `selectedCountry` is supposed to be an object? in that case please try passing the Select value as `selectedCountry.name`:

```
<Select
  labelId="country-label"
  id="country"
  value={selectedCountry.name}
  onChange={handleChangeCountry}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
```